# Solving the recurrence $t(n)=(t(n-1))^2 + 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following recurrence relation:
\begin{align*}
t(1) & = 1, \\
t(n) & =(t(n-1))^2 + 1.
\end{align*}
I need to prove that $t(n)= k^{2^{n}}$ for some constant $k$. What is the value of $k$?

How would I go about doing it? thanks

Comment: If you mean that $t(n)=(t(n-1))^2+1$, then the formula $k^{2n}$ is not correct, as a calculation of the first few terms will show. So there may be a typo.  And if you mean asymptotically equal, that doesn't work either, the function as given grows far faster than $k^{2n}$.

Comment: yes is t(n)= (t(n-1))^2 +1    the formula is k^2^n

Comment: @oscar Even after editing, what you are trying to prove is false. Let $n=1$. Then we have $k^2=1$, so $k=\pm 1$. But this would imply $t(n)=1$ for all $n$, which is trivially false.

Comment: Are you familiar with proof by induction in general? Do you know how to start such a proof?

Comment: @EdGorcenski i dont now how formula use, T(n)=T(n-1)^2 + 1 or T(n)=k^2^n in the induction

Comment: Please refer to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html#eqn3

Comment: The domain of $n$ is in complex numbers or just in integers?

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Since $t(n)\geqslant1$, $t(n+1)+1=t(n)^2+2\leqslant(t(n)+1)^2$ for every $n\geqslant1$. Iterating and using the initial condition $t(1)+1=2$, one gets $t(n)+1\leqslant2^{2^{n-1}}$, hence $t(n)\lt2^{2^{n-1}}$ for every $n\geqslant1$.

On the other hand, $t(n+1)\gt t(n)^2$ for every $n\geqslant1$. Iterating and using the initial condition $t(2)=2$, one gets $t(n)\gt2^{2^{n-2}}$ for every $n\geqslant2$.

For every $n\geqslant2$, $a^{2^n}\lt t(n)\lt b^{2^n}$ with $a=\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $b=\sqrt{2}$.

Conjecture: $\log_2\log_2 t(n)=n-\kappa+o(1)$ for some $1\leqslant\kappa\lt2$.

**Edit:** The [OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A003095) suggested by @Gerry Myerson asserts that $\kappa$ exists and provides a numerical value equivalent to $\kappa=1.7668768^-$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is tabulated [here](http://oeis.org/A003095), and there are some links that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since T(n) = k^(2^n), T(1) = 1 = k^(2^1) = k^2

Hence, k = 1 or k = -1, which doesn't make sense at all.

You sure you got the question right?

Answer (score 0):

If $T(n)=T(n-1)^2+1$ => $T(n)=(T(n-1))^2+1$

If $T(n)=k^{2^n}$ for some k,

$(T(n-1))^2+1 =  ({k^{{2^{n-1}}})^2}+1 = k^{2^n}+1 $ which can not be equal to $k^{2^n}=T(n)$

What's wrong in these steps?

Comment: I think we all know $t(n)$ can't *equal* $k^{2^n}$. We've moved on to noting that it is *asymptotic* to $k^{2^n}$, for an appropriate choice of $k$.

Comment: As noted in one of the answers before (and of course in your own answer), it is in fact better than 'just' asymptotic; the relation is so tight that one can find a $k$ such that $t(n) = \left\lfloor k^{2^n}\right\rfloor$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this recurrence belongs to a linear shifting version of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html#eqn3.

So according to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html#eqn3, this recurrence has the analytical solution when $n$ is any natural number:

$t(n)=\biggl[e^{2^{n-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}\ln\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{y_k^2}\Bigr)}\biggr]$

For $n$ is any complex number, I still have no idea about its analytical solution.