# Recurrence relation induction

Tags: recurrence-relations, trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solving the recurrence $t(n)=(t(n-1))^2 + 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171731/solving-the-recurrence-tn-tn-12-1)

> Show that the number of binary trees of height less than or equal to $n$ is given by the recurrence
>
> \begin{align*}
> T(1) & = 1, \\
> T(n) & = T(n- 1)^2 + 1.
> \end{align*}
>
> Show that $T(n) = k^{2^n}$ for some constant $k$. What is the value of $k$?

I'm really lost, how can start to solve it?

Comment: Am I missing something? It's wrong as in Alex Becker's comment? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171731/recurrence-relation#comment394662_171731

Comment: You might want to merge this question with [the other one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/171731).